# Are there any clojure tools to see how Clojure uses JVM memory?

Tags: clojure

I would like to be able to analyze my Clojure program to see how the memory is used. Are there any tools to do this?

Update: I have tried the JVM tools mentioned in the answers but none of these tools allow me to visualise any of my clojure data structures, although they do give me some indication

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[jvisualvm](http://visualvm.java.net/) allows you to do that

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Apparently only you and dogbane understood the question as someone else downvoted the question. I guess some people don't know the difference between Java and Clojure and that they both run on the JVM :)

Answer (score 5):

Perform a jvm heap dump using [`jmap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html). You can then load the dump into [Eclipse Memory Analyser](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) which will show you where memory is being used. Alternatively, you can just use [`jhat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jhat.html) to browse the heap dump.

Comment: I tried this. I get a dump of all the Java classes. It is still quite hard to map each Java instance to the clojure equivalent though. Did you try it with a Java or a Clojure program?